# Ruby - overwrite def method

Tags: ruby, class, object

How can I overwrite the **def** method?  But it's strange, cause I don't know from where the def method is defined.  It's not Module, not Object, not BasicObject (of Ruby 1.9).  And def.class don't say nothing ;)

I would like to use something like:

```
sub_def hello
  puts "Hello!"
  super
end

def hello
  puts "cruel world."
end

# ...and maybe it could print:
# => "Hello!"
# => "cruel world."
```

Many thanks, for any ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Who told you `def` is a method? It's not. It's a keyword, like `class`, `if`, `end`, etc. So you cannot overwrite it, unless you want to write your own ruby interpreter.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's better for me to just use some DSL blocks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use alias_method.

```
alias_method :orig_hello, :hello
def hello
  puts "Hello!"
  orig_hello
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use blocks to do some similar things like this:

```
def hello
  puts "Hello"
  yield if block_given?
end

hello do
 puts "cruel world"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `def` isn't a method, it's a keyword. You can't "override" it. You can, however, define a method called "def" via Ruby metaprogramming magic:

```
define_method :def do
  puts "this is a bad idea"
end
```

This still won't override the `def` keyword, but you can call your new method with `method(:def).call`.

So, there you (sort of) have it.

Note: I have no idea why you'd ever want to define a method called `def`. Don't do it.